# How to make group colorbar xticks yticks in Seaborn or Matplotplib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Given an array `normal_data` with a label `mgroup`, the following heatmap is generated.

[image]

But, I wonder whether it is possible using Matplotlib or Seaborn to have a xtick-ytick color bar (The rectangle shape of color blue, orange, light green, dark blue, dark green) to represent a group membership, as shown above?

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
mgroup=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5])
normal_data = np.random.randn(12, 12)

ax = sns.heatmap(normal_data, center=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: what are your values for "group membership" or "mgroup"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `plt.Rectangle` to draw colored rectangles. Setting `clip_on=False` allows drawing outside the main axes. The [xaxis transform](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) uses x in the horizontal direction, and axes coordinates in the y direction. The yaxis transform works similar in the other orientation.

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mgroup = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5])
normal_data = np.random.randn(12, 12)

grouping = [3, 2, 4, 1, 2]
colors = ['dodgerblue', 'orange', 'lime', 'darkblue', 'green']
labels = [f'Group {i + 1}' for i in range(len(colors))]
ax = sns.heatmap(normal_data, center=0, cbar_kws={'orientation': 'horizontal', 'pad': 0.08})

for width, pos, color, label in zip(grouping, np.cumsum([0] + grouping), colors, labels):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((pos, 1.02), width, 0.1, color=color,
                               clip_on=False, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform()))
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((1.02, pos), 0.1, width, color=color,
                               clip_on=False, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform()))
    ax.text(1.14, pos + width/2, label, ha='left', va='center', clip_on=False, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: colored x and y grouping]

Comment: I see. It's a way to stack rectangles. This is very simple. My answer was the result of a lot of sweating and struggling. Up vote +1

Answer (score 2):

For the group values, we use np.unique() to get the array and frequency, and use that to create a stacked graph. The created graphs are placed on the right and top of the heat map, with new axes added to them. As for the labels, I decided their positions manually. I am getting there by hand to complete this, so it may not be the best way. Also, some of the code may be redundant.

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mgroup=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,5])
normal_data = np.random.randn(12, 12)
u,counts = np.unique(mgroup, return_counts=True)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':counts},index=u)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(4,4), sharey=True)# , sharey=True
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.0,0.8,0.05])
g = sns.heatmap(normal_data, center=0, cbar_ax=cbar_ax, cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"}, ax=axs)
#g.set_aspect('auto')
df_ax = fig.add_axes([0.9,0.12,0.05,0.80])
d = df.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=0.7, legend=False, ax=df_ax)
d.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
d.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
d.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
d.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
df_ax.set_xticks([])
df_ax.set_yticks([])

df_ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.12,0.85,0.82,0.05])
d = df.T.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, width=0.7, legend=False, ax=df_ax2)
d.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
d.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
d.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
d.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
df_ax2.set_xticks([])
df_ax2.set_yticks([])

df_ax.text(1.0, 0.20, 'Group5', transform=fig.transFigure)
df_ax.text(1.0, 0.35, 'Group4', transform=fig.transFigure)
df_ax.text(1.0, 0.55, 'Group3', transform=fig.transFigure)
df_ax.text(1.0, 0.70, 'Group2', transform=fig.transFigure)
df_ax.text(1.0, 0.80, 'Group1', transform=fig.transFigure)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see you comment up there, thanks for the time. +1 from me

Comment: I would replace `plt.show()` with `fig.show()` at the end, just to get rid of things that are not object-orientated.